# Arbitrary chapter number

Tags: numbering, chapters

I want to numbering the title of my chapters in a different manner and with my selected word. For example, I want my first chapter numbered AA and the second one FR and etc. How can I do that . My code is:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}


\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{15}\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{} 


\begin{document}
\chapter{Apple}
It is for test
\Chapter{Book}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not recommending this: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{AA}` etc. separately for each of the 'special' 'numbering' occurences. There is a typo: `\Chapter` → `\chapter`. Since `AA` is followed by `FR` I can't see a definitive scheme in order to `calculate` such a chapter 'number'

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : Is there any command that I change seperate numbers of any chapter to my favorites. For example, change {Chapter #1} to {Chapter AA},  {Chapter #2} to {Chapter FR}, and etc

Comment: Are you sticking to `titlesec`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : No, there is no insistence on it.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by your typo, `\Chapter`, I defined a command `\Chapter` that takes two arguments, the "number" of the chapter and its title.

Then I changed the `\titleformat` to make it use the "number" of the chapter that you give.

If you use a normal `\chapter`, the actual chapter number is used instead.

Beware! As @ChristianHupfer noted, even if you use `\Chapter{FR}{Book}`, in the table of contents it still will be `Chapter II Book`. [His answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417915/134574) takes care of the ToC numbering too :)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\edef\chaptersymbol{}%
\newcommand{\Chapter}[2]{%
\edef\chaptersymbol{#1}%
\chapter{#2}%
\edef\chaptersymbol{}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{15}\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \ifx\chaptersymbol\empty\thechapter\else\chaptersymbol\fi}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{} 


\begin{document}
\chapter{Apple}
It is for test
\Chapter{FR}{Book}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution does provide 'wrong' chapter numbers in the ToC and with `\ref`....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hmmm, indeed. I didn't think of that :/

Answer (score 3):

I've defined a `\seq` variable that contains a list of desired numbers or 'texts' that should be used as numbers. The numbers are retrieved by the real chapter number with `\seq_item:Nn`, more can be added with `\addtonumberpool` (see code below).

This solution takes care of the ToC and the reference format.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{20pt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_raihaneh_numberpool_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtonumberpool}{+m}{%
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_raihaneh_numberpool_seq {##1}
  }
  \group_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\populatenumberpool}{+m}{%
  \addtonumberpool{#1}
}


\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \mychapternumberexpression {%
  \cs_set:Npx \thechapter {\seq_item:Nn \g_raihaneh_numberpool_seq  {\int_eval:n {\value{chapter}+1}}}
}


\xpretocmd{\@chapter}{%
  \mychapternumberexpression
}{}{}

\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\populatenumberpool{AA,FR}

\addtonumberpool{BAD,TYPOGRAPHY}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

See \ref{apple} or \ref{book} or \ref{stuff}

\chapter{Apple} \label{apple}
It is for test
\chapter{Book} \label{book}

\chapter{Stuff} \label{stuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_raihaneh_numberpool_seq {##1} }` be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the sequence of the chapter numbers and redefine accordingly `\thechapter`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definechapternumbers}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_raihaneh_chapters_clist { #1 }
 }
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thechapter}{}
 {
  \clist_item:Nn \g_raihaneh_chapters_clist { \value{chapter} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definechapternumbers{AA,FR}

% make a bit more room for the chapter numbers in the TOC
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.5em}{2.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax % just not to have page breaks

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Apple}\label{chap:apple}

This is chapter~\ref{chap:apple}

\chapter{Book}\label{chap:book}

This is chapter~\ref{chap:book}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it depends, if you want to define the chapter numbering independently of the chapter name. Then, having a number pool in some centralized location is desirable. But, if like in Phelype's answer, you want the numbering close to the chapter name, i. e., in the same location, then having a macro with two options is nicer. Depends on the OP's doc design, I guess. In any case, having the correct labels in the TOC is paramount, as otherwise, it's just confusing for the readers. Nicely done (I would so much love to learn expl syntax!).